# Using `:not(:last-child)` on child elements won't skip the real last element

Tags: css

Using `:not(:last-child)` on child elements won't skip the **real** last element if there more not only the **same class** in the same parent.

Example shows that event I **only** give the `margin-bottom: 5px` to all `.blue` elements except the last `.blue` element, the last `.blue` element still has the `margin-bottom: 5px` styling.

Anyone knows how should I make this working or provide a documentation that explains how should I avoid this. Thanks in advance.

```css
.blue,
.red {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.blue:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="blue">first blue text</div>
  <div class="blue">blue text2</div>
  <div class="blue">blue text3</div>
  <div class="blue">blue text4</div>
  <div class="blue">last blue text</div>
  <div class="red">red text</div>
  <div class="red">red text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child):

> The :last-child CSS pseudo-class represents the last element among a group of sibling elements.

It does not refer to the last of a particular class. The selector `.blue:not(:last-child)` matches all elements that are `.blue` and not the last child in the NodeList encapsulated by `.box`. In your example `last-child` means the second `.red` element.

It is not actually possible to select by the last of a particular class or selector. The closest we have is `last-of-type` which as the name suggests will select the last of a particular element type. For example:

```css
h2:last-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>First Heading</h2>
<h2>Second Heading</h2>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The :last-child CSS pseudo-class represents the last element among a group of sibling elements. <sup>[Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)</sup>

There is no *"last-of-class"* selector existing... The only way to target that element is to add a specific class to it.

You could use JavaScript to do it instead of doing it manually in the markup:

```js
let all_blue = document.querySelectorAll(".blue");
Array.from(all_blue).slice(-1)[0].classList.add("last-blue");
```

```css
.blue,
.red {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.blue:not(.last-blue) { /* .last-blue is used here */
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="blue">first blue text</div>
  <div class="blue">blue text2</div>
  <div class="blue">blue text3</div>
  <div class="blue">blue text4</div>
  <div class="blue">last blue text</div>
  <div class="red">red text</div>
  <div class="red">red text</div>
</div>
```